# Google map locality label covered behind Poligon

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, maps, google-maps-markers, react-google-maps

I used `react-google-maps` `withGoogleMap` for the google map in ReactJs, also I am using `styles` to change the custom view of my google map. in that map i have many `polygons` with fill color.

the problem is that, my custom `polygons` covered google map locality labels, so unable read proper label name.

here is my code

```
<GoogleMap
        options={{
          streetViewControl: false,
          fullScreenControl: false,
          disableDefaultUI: true,
          styles: mapStyle,
        }}
      >
```

here is the issue screenshot.
[image]

in the image you can see, it's unable to read the label behind the `polygons`

so how can I set labels top of the `polygons`?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the opacity level of the polygon on 'zoom_changed'.

So when the level of zoom is lower you can set the opacity level to below 1 and when it's higher you can set it to 1.

Check out this example here:

```
map.addListener('zoom_changed', () => {
    let zoom = map.getZoom();
    console.log("zoom changed: " + zoom);
    if (zoom < 6) {
      polygon.setOptions({
        fillOpacity: 0.3
      })
    } else {
        polygon.setOptions({
        fillOpacity: 1
      })
    }
  })
}
```

Well, I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

I believe what happens when you create a polygon on the map is that it overlays the map which will overlay all the labels too, you can set opacity to below 1.

This is how you would do it using plain JS:

```
const polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
paths: triangleCoords,
strokeColor: "#FF0000",
strokeOpacity: 0.8,
strokeWeight: 2,
fillColor: "#FF0000",
fillOpacity: 0.35,
```

});

Comment: @jummyP thanks for you answer but for some visibility I can not change the fillOpacity, it must be 1

Comment: This would be the only workaround in this case. Because it's a layer on top of the map, it will cover all labels. Why must it be 1?

Comment: polygons are to many and with very small size, si its hard to find with low opacity when we have minimum zoom

Comment: Okay, I understand, it might even be a little bit better at 0.9 or 0.95 opacity though.

Comment: You can map the opacity to the zoom level, so as you zoom out more you can reduce the opacity. This way you can still see polygons when zoomed in and see the labels when zoomed out. Use the method from the Maps JavaScript API here to do it (zoom_changed): https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events#EventsOverview